# Rake not able to migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

```
C:\Users\MEGHA\bbbb>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: C:/Users/MEGHA/bbbb/db/migrate/20140402130040_create_comments.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
C:65535:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

20140402130040_create_comments.rb

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :post_id=integer
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NOT able to rake db:migrate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806780/not-able-to-rake-dbmigrate). Questioner, I have voted to close this question as a duplicate of the one where you have accepted an answer. In the future, please refrain from posting the same question more than once.

Answer (score 1):

instead:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :post_id=integer #<= this 
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

use

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer :post_id
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your migration you have used

> :post_id = integer

Instead it needs to be as below:

```
 class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
```

> ```
>  create_table :comments do |t|
>     t.integer :post_id
>     t.text :body
>     t.timestamps
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> end